# Enable python calculator when compiling paraview 5.5.0

Tags: paraview

I am trying to compile Paraview 5.5.0 from source code. After compiling and running Paraview in Debug mode, I cannot find "python Calculator" in my Filters. I will be thankful if you please let me know which flag I have to set on CMAKE. "Module_vtkPythonInterpreter" is already set.

Comment: Can you precise the version of ParaView ?

Comment: Paraview source code version is 5.5.0

Comment: python version is 3.7

Answer (score 1):

With ParaView 5.5, turning `PARAVIEW_ENABLE_PYTHON` to `ON` is enough.